# Simplest way to build a semantic analyzer

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, nlp, model-selection

I want to build a semantic analyzer i.e., to find how similar the meaning of two sentences are. 
For example-
English: Birdie is washing itself in the water basin.
English Paraphrase: The bird is bathing in the sink.
Similarity Score: 5 ( The two sentences are completely equivalent, as they mean the same thing.)

I have to find the similarity between the meaning of those sentences.

Here is a github repo of what I want to implement.
https://github.com/anantm95/Semantic-Textual-Similarity

Is there any simpler approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any simpler approach?

Very unlikely, semantic similarity is a very complex problem related to [Natural Language Understanding (NLU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_understanding). You could look at the techniques used for [textual entailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_entailment), [Question Answering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) and [summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization).

Simple methods like the baseline system proposed in the github link, but they don't really try to analyze the semantics.